# Colon-generated arrays with or without brackets in Matlab

Tags: matlab

From what I can tell, the arrays `a:d:b` and `[a:d:b]` are exactly the same thing. For example,

```
>> [1:3] == 1:3
ans =
  1×3 logical array
   1   1   1
```

Yet, these two expressions give different results:

```
>> [1:3]' + 1:3
ans =
     2     3

>> [1:3]' + [1:3]
ans =
     2     3     4
     3     4     5
     4     5     6
```

Why?

(I am using Matlab R2017b 9.3.0.713579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good answer came from Rik Wisselink on this forum:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/391046-colon-generated-arrays-with-or-without-brackets

> The reason for this is the unexpected order in which this statement is
>   evaluated:
>
> ```
> [1:3]' + 1:3  
> ([1:3]' + 1):3  
> ([1;2;3]+1):3  
> [2;3;4]:3  
> 2:3  
> [2,3]
> ```
>
> Adding the brackets forces the grouping before and after the colon
>   operator (parentheses would have worked as well).

Stephen Cobeldick adds that this is explained by the fact that `+` has a higher priority than `:`.

Steven Lord also comments that the transition from line 4 to 5 is explained in the documentation:

> If you specify nonscalar arrays, then MATLAB interprets j:i:k as j(1):i(1):k(1).